Last Oracle user UNlocked date/time
dba_users has the column lock_date .. perfect, but, is there a column LAST_UNLOCK_DATE (anywhere)?
We need to know when an account was unlocked last time.
Thank you!

No, but you can create a system (after ddl on database) trigger to capture DDL and use that going forward. ora_sysevent will be ALTER, ora_dict_obj_type will be USER and you can use original_sql_txt to get an array of SQL pieces that you can reassemble into the DDL statement. Then you apply UPPER() and look for %UNLOCK%

alternatively you can simply enable normal auditing so that it captures DDL and query the audit trail.
